# UIViewPropertyAnimator not respecting duration and delay parameters

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have a very strange issue in my app. I'm using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to animate changing images inside `UIImageView`.

Sounds like trivial task but for some reaso my view ends up changing the image instantly so I end up with images flashing at light speed instead of given duration and delay parameters.

Here's the code:

```
private lazy var images: [UIImage?] = [
    UIImage(named: "widgethint"),
    UIImage(named: "shortcuthint"),
    UIImage(named: "spotlighthint")
]
private var imageIndex = 0
private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    animator = repeatingAnimator()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    animator?.stopAnimation(true)
}

private func repeatingAnimator() -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
    return .runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 2, delay: 6, options: [], animations: {
        self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex]
    }, completion: { pos in
        if self.imageIndex >= self.images.count - 1 {
            self.imageIndex = 0
        } else {
            self.imageIndex += 1
        }
        self.animator = self.repeatingAnimator()
    })
}
```

So, according to the code animation should take 2 seconds to complete and start after 6 seconds delay, but it starts immediately and takes milliseconds to complete so I end up with horrible slideshow. Why could it be happening?

I also tried using the `UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear)` and calling `repeatingAnimator().startAnimation(afterDelay: 6)` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out, but it's still a bit annoying that such simple task cannot be done using the "Modern" animation API.

So, animating images inside `UIImageView` is apparently not supported by `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, during debugging I tried animating view's background color and it was working as expected. So I had to use `Timer` instead and old `UIView.transition(with:)` method

Here's the working code:

```
private let animationDelay: TimeInterval = 2.4

private var animationTimer: Timer!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    setAnimation(true)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    setAnimation(false)
}

private func setAnimation(_ enabled: Bool) {
    guard enabled else {
        animationTimer?.invalidate()
        animationTimer = nil
        return
    }
    animationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDelay, repeats: true) { _ in
        UIView.transition(with: self.imageView, duration: 0.5, options: [.curveLinear, .transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex]
        }, completion: { succ in
            guard succ else {
                return
            }
            if self.imageIndex >= self.images.count - 1 {
                self.imageIndex = 0
            } else {
                self.imageIndex += 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Hopefully it will save someone some headaches in the future